# Using shortcodes with bxslider

Tags: php, wordpress

So I'm building a shortcode so that I can use with bxSlider (https://bxslider.com/examples/image-slideshow-captions/) but for some reason I am unable to have my javascript work.

Here is the example of my shortcode:

```
[slider]
[slide headline="Hack Your Newsfeed" image="/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/M2020DayOne.jpg" body="<p>Test.</p>" link="Learn How Now|https://www.howtogeek.com/665935/how-to-sort-your-facebook-feed-by-most-recent/"]
[slide headline="Branch Out" image="/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/M2020DayOne.jpg" body="<p>Test</p>" link="Facebook|https://facebook.com" link="Instagram|https://instagram.com"]
[/slider]
```

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
function slider_wrapper_shortcode($atts, $content = null)
{
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
            [
                'id' => '',
            ], $atts, 'slider');

    $id = $atts['id'] ?: rawurldecode(sanitize_title($atts['title']));

    $cleaned_content = wpautop(trim($content));

    $output = '<div id="bxslider' . $id . '" class="bxslider">';
    $output .= do_shortcode($cleaned_content);
    $output .= '</div>';

    $output .= '<script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                        jQuery(".bxslider").bxSlider({
                            pager: false,
                            auto: true,
                            pause: 3000,
                            captions: false,
                        })
                    })
                </script>';

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('slider', 'slider_wrapper_shortcode');

function slide_item_shortcode($atts, $content = null)
{
    extract(shortcode_atts([
            "image" => 'image',
        ], $atts)
    );

    return '<div><img src="' . home_url(esc_url($image)) . '" alt="" /></div>';
}
add_shortcode('slide', 'slide_item_shortcode');
```

Here is how the shortcodes are being rendered currently:

```
<div id="bxslider" class="bxslider">
<p></p><div><img src="https://*****.com.local/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/M2020DayOne.jpg" alt=""></div>
<p></p>
<p></p><div><img src="https://*****.com.local/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/M2020DayOne.jpg" alt=""></div>
<p></p>
</div>
```

For some reason, it looks like the script tag is not being detected at all, since I don't see a reference in my console at all.

Update:

[image]

Comment: I placed your code in a staging site and do see that the script is being concatenated to the output. Is there a chance that there's another plugin using "slider" or "slide" on your site? I had to change the shortcode slugs to "theslider" and "theslide" to prevent namespace conflicts.

Comment: @JamesRyvenValeii thanks so much James! Looks like I didn't have the bxslider enqueued - However, how that I do, I'm not getting any content.

I'll update with a screenshot.

Comment: The image definitely has something there, because when I hover over the url, I can see the image.

Comment: You should see the script just below <div class="bx-slider"></div> ... it's not in your screenshot.

Comment: @JamesRyvenValeii, so it looks like its enqueued since I'm seeing `<script type='text/javascript' src='https://*****/wp-content/themes/***/scripts/jquery.bxslider.min.js?ver=2.0.0'></script>` in my footer.

Comment: This should do it for you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63492230/using-shortcodes-with-bxslider/63493525#63493525#answer-63493525

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the empty `<p>` tags before you shortcodes. This is a common problem with shortcodes entered into the WP editor. There are a few ways to tackle this:

**1. autop** - You can change the priority of `autop` to run later, by adding this to your functions.php:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' , 99);
```

**2. Remove empty p tags** If that affects other output, you can use this function to remove the empty `<p></p>` tags from your output:

```
function my_stripemptytags($content){
    $pattern = "/<p[^>]*><\\/p[^>]*>/"; // remove empty p tags
    return preg_replace($pattern, '', $content); 
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_stripemptytags', 100 );
```

**Missing unique id**

You are also not getting a unique id because this code is trying to generate it from `title` being passed into the shortcode:

```
$atts = shortcode_atts(
        [
            'id' => '',
        ], $atts, 'slider');

// NOTE: THERE IS NO $atts['title']
$id = $atts['id'] ?: rawurldecode(sanitize_title($atts['title']));
```

However you are not passing in or checking for a `title` attribute in your shortcode.

If you are looking to use the post id, you can get it like this:

```
global $post;
$title = $post->title;
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use shortcodes inside a shortcode, even though it seems to work, it has consequences the wordpress editor processes the content and converts all line breaks to html and more. This does not guarantee that you will receive the structure you need.

but if you want a solution, then there is (not recommend)

1.) correct your code first (Follow the comments)

```
function slider_wrapper_shortcode($atts, $content = null)
{
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
            [
                'id' => '',
            ], $atts, 'slider');

    // You need to use isset or empty methods for data validation 
    // (you had a mistake here, you didn't have a title in the attributes of shortcode

    $title = isset($atts['title']) ? $atts['title'] : "";

    // same
    $id = !empty($atts['id']) ? $atts['id'] : rawurldecode(sanitize_title($title));
   
    // don`t use wpautop method
    $cleaned_content = trim($content); // wpautop

    $output = '<div id="bxslider_' . $id . '" class="bxslider">';
    $output .= do_shortcode($cleaned_content);
    $output .= '</div>';

    $output .= '<script type="text/javascript">
                  // Wrap your code
                  (function($) {
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        // Check if plugin exists
                        if ($.fn.bxSlider) {
                           // don`t use class, you must use a unique id
                           $("#bxslider_'.$id.'").bxSlider({
                               pager: false,
                               auto: true,
                               pause: 3000,
                               captions: false,
                           })
                        }
                    });
                  })(jQuery);
                </script>';    
    return $output;
}
```

And use your shortcodes but without a single space

```
[slider][slide headline="Hack Your Newsfeed" image="/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/M2020DayOne.jpg" body="Test." link="Learn How Now|https://www.howtogeek.com/665935/how-to-sort-your-facebook-feed-by-most-recent/"][slide headline="Branch Out" image="/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/M2020DayOne.jpg" body="Test" link="Facebook|https://facebook.com" link="Instagram|https://instagram.com"][/slider]
```

**I checked it returns what you need**

---

Result:
[image]

Full code

```
function slider_wrapper_shortcode($atts, $content = null)
{
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
            [
                'id' => '',
            ], $atts, 'slider');

    $title = isset($atts['title']) ? $atts['title'] : "";

    $id = !empty($atts['id']) ? $atts['id'] : rawurldecode(sanitize_title($title));
    $cleaned_content = trim($content); // wpautop

    $output = '<div id="bxslider_' . $id . '" class="bxslider">';
    $output .= do_shortcode($cleaned_content);
    $output .= '</div>';

    $output .= '<script type="text/javascript">
                                    (function($) {
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        // Check if plugin exists
                        if ($.fn.bxSlider) {
                           // don`t use class, you must use a unique id
                           $("#bxslider_'.$id.'").bxSlider({
                               pager: false,
                               auto: true,
                               pause: 3000,
                               captions: false,
                           })
                        }
                    });
                  })(jQuery);
                </script>';

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('slider', 'slider_wrapper_shortcode');

function slide_item_shortcode($atts, $content = null)
{
    extract(shortcode_atts([
            "image" => 'image',
        ], $atts)
    );

    return '<div><img src="' . home_url(esc_url($image)) . '" alt="" /></div>';
}
add_shortcode('slide', 'slide_item_shortcode');
```

Comment: Wow trying this now! Do I still need the `slide_item_shortcode` function then for shortcode slide? or is that included in the wrapper?

Comment: Although nested shortcodes do complicate things, WordPress Codex does not discourage the use of nested shortcodes in any manner: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Limitations

Comment: Yes, you should also use your second shortcode function, I just did not change it

Comment: @Unbywyd, thanks so much for helping out! Now all I see are two images and I can't slide them back and forth at all.

I see the JS code in the console and I also have `<script type='text/javascript' src='https://***/wp-content/themes/***/scripts/jquery.bxslider.min.js?ver=2.0.0'></script>` enqueued.

Comment: I see <div id="bxslider" class="bxslider"> but no unique id.

Comment: You can set unique id for your slider in attribute  [slider id="23"] or  change your php to:  $id = uniqid();

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a functioning slideshow using your code, with some added parameters and outputs:

```
    function slider_wrapper_shortcode($atts, $content = null)
    {
        $atts = shortcode_atts(
                [
                    'title' => '',
                    'id' => '',
                ], $atts, 'slider');

        $id = $atts['id'] ?: rawurldecode(sanitize_title($atts['title']));

        $cleaned_content = wpautop(trim($content));

        $output = '<div id="bxslider' . $id . '" class="bxslider">';
        $output .= do_shortcode($cleaned_content);
        $output .= '</div>';

        $output .= '<script type="text/javascript">
                        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                            jQuery(".bxslider").bxSlider({
                                pager: false,
                                auto: true,
                                pause: 3000,
                                captions: false,
                            })
                        })
                    </script>';

        return $output;
    }
    add_shortcode('theslider', 'slider_wrapper_shortcode');

    function slide_item_shortcode($atts, $content = null)
    {
        extract(shortcode_atts([
                "image" => '',
                "headline" => '',
                "body" => '',
                "link" => '',
            ], $atts)
        );

        return '<div>
                <img src="' . esc_url($atts['image']) . '" alt="" />
                <p>'.$atts['headline'].'</p>
                <p>'.$atts['body'].'</p>
                <p>'.$atts['link'].'</p>
                </div>';
    }
    add_shortcode('theslide', 'slide_item_shortcode');
    ?>
```

Called via:

```
    [theslider]
    [theslide headline="Title" image="https://via.placeholder.com/150" body="<p>Test.</p>" link="Learn How Now|https://www.howtogeek.com/665935/how-to-sort-your-facebook-feed-by-most-recent/"]
    [theslide headline="Branch Out" image="https://via.placeholder.com/150" body="<p>Test</p>" link="Facebook|https://facebook.com" link="Instagram|https://instagram.com"]
    [/theslider]
```